# use relative folder included html files

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a web-page where there are common html docs so I used jQuery to include them into all .html

The problem is that my index html file it's in the project folder and the other files there are in their own folder inside the project folder. That included files has img sources and had different paths in the index file and the others

i.e

```
myproject/index.html
myproject/commonFiles/header.html
myproject/contact/contact.html
myproject/sources
```

if header.html defines img tag with `src="./img1.jpg"` it will only works for index.html

The main idea is not moving contact to another folder because there are more files like that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<base href="">` tag in `<head>` area.

http://html.com/attributes/base-href/

Answer (score 0):

Use root-relative path that starts with a `/`

Both in the pages while loading:

```
$("#footer").load("/common/footer.html");
```

Also in the loaded file:

```
src="/img1.jpg"
```

It must always start with a `/` which denotes the root folder

Comment: @ Anupam Majhi it doesn't work because images are in sources folder, I can reach it from index file but no from contact file

Comment: Can you tell me this:
1. Are you running your code from local folder directly or a localhost (XAMPP or LAMP or any real web server)?
2. Is you code in the root directory? or subdirectory?

Comment: I'm running from local folder and it is in a subdirectory

Comment: It doesn't work unless you have a server.
If you are trying development in your system , try installing a local server like XAMPP or MAMP to see how it works in real servers.